# how to find the best suitable buffer size to read or write Stream based on the current server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, stream

I am writing a server which will ready and write huge files / database.

I have used Stream read and write functions many places where I am using 8192 as buffer size.

I am also reading large input from TCP sockets.

I don't know what would be the configuration of the VMs where the service will be deployed.

Is there any built in function using which I can determine the best suitable buffer size for my server?

Answer (score 3):

I often wondered this myself. But in the end I do not hink that there is a general rule to apply. It always comes down to your specific needs.

As a rule of thumb, if your buffer is bigger you need less roundtrips to the file system or database, which in general, is best for most cases.

However, how much data your system can read into memory at once, without making other applications, is very depending on your individual environment. Some mobile device might have different specifics than your over-the-top server hardware, and so on.

Other things to consider would be network bandwith and other shared resources, as well as the sheer performance impact on your actions.

For example, at a project with thousands of image files, we found after several tries that - for us - the idela buffer size was at around 1 MB. For images with a size lower than that we used a buffer size equal to the file size. For your scenario this would of course not fit.

Rico Mariani, performance expert at Microsoft, names the 10 most important aspects of programming for performance: Measure, measure, measure, measure, ... (You get the point. :-) )

Comment: thanks for the informations... , still I wonder there should be something written that they uses , suppose if I use 8192 as buffer size, is there any possiblity that this large buffer size is not supported in some old VM, in that senario they must be having some function which atleast returns the maximum buffer size.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on throughput, communication channel utilization and connection stability in production environment.
From my point of view, the best here is to make an adaptive algorithm, which will change buffer size, depending on factors mentioned above.

**UPDATE**.
Be careful when using buffer, that is equals or larger than 85000 bytes. Such buffers should be reused as much, as possible (because of LOH behavior).

Comment: thanks for the answer dennis, do you know how .net determines the buffer size for stream reading writing built in functions?

Comment: @ImranRizvi: what "built in functions" do you mean?

Comment: when we use some functions given for writing text files to the disk (FileInfo's WriteLine etc.) that do not accept buffer size parameter , I am supposing that internally they uses some buffer size to write the data.

Comment: AFAIK, they're using constant values.

Answer (score 2):

The critical factor is not the size of the application's buffer but the size of the socket send and receive buffers, which must be >= the bandwidth-delay product of the link. Any increase above that should yield zero benefit; any decrease below it will become visible in suboptimal bandwidth. Application buffers have a role to play in reducing system calls but 8192 is normally quite enough for most purposes, especially networking ones.